# Passing array of inputs through the same test

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

**Context:** End-to-end testing in Angular JS using Protractor

**Goal:** I want to run the same test against many different values. Ideally looping through an array of values and running the same `it` block for each.

**Problem:** Since Protractor will run the tests asynchronously any test inside a `for` loop will be executed after the loop finishes.

For example,

```
var values = ['...','...'];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  it('should do something good', function() {
    // some test using this particular value in the values array
  });
}
```

However (say there are 10 items in the array), the result is the the test runs 10 times where the value of `i` is `9` each time, instead of `0,1,2,3...` as expected. This has to do with the asynchronous nature of the tests.

**What I've tried:** Using a `done()` callback according to the answer of [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634558/looping-on-a-protractor-test-with-parameters/21704776).

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  it('should do something good', function (done) {
    // some test using this particular value in the values array
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });
}
```

**Why that didn't work:** I get the following error:

```
/node_modules/protractor/jasminewd/index.js:44
        throw new Error('Do not use a done callback with WebDriverJS tests
              ^
Error: Do not use a done callback with WebDriverJS tests. The tests are patched to be asynchronous and will terminate when the webdriver control flow is empty.
at null._onTimeout (/Users/drew/apps/hotrod/node_modules/protractor/jasminewd/index.js:44:19)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Any ideas on how to loop through an array of values and run the same tests against each? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found!** The trick is to wrap the contents of the loop in an immediately invoked function and pass in an explicit param with each iteration of the loop.

Check it out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635357/1526027