# loop through it() in jasmine describe output spec not found

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I learned that [this way](http://tosbourn.com/using-loops-in-jasmine/) is the best way to loop through the it() in a describe(), but it failed on me with "spec not found", and seems stop right before the for loop function, I wonder where did I do wrong?

Thanks!

```
describe('this is my looping test!', function() {
  var input = [1,2,3];
  var output = [10, 20, 30];

  function test_my_times_ten(input, output) {
    it('should multiply ' + input + ' by 10 to give ' + output, function() {
      expect(input * 10).toEqual(output)
    });
  }

  for(var x = 0; x < input.size; x++) {
    test_my_times_ten(input[x], output[x]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using it("..", cb) outside of the loop ? Does it work?

Comment: @elad.chen Not sure how would that work.... would you demonstrate what you mean? Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually someone did really smart thing like this, and it seems does the work!

[Looping on a protractor test with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634558/looping-on-a-protractor-test-with-parameters/23635357#23635357)

```
var testParams = testConfig.testArray;

for (var i = 0; i < testParams.length; i++) {

  (function (testSpec) {
    it('write your test here', function () {
      //test code here
    });
  })(testParams[i]);

};
```

Comment: While I'm not a fan of looping in tests, this is actually the correct way to do it.

Comment: @MBielski hum... why not though? Doesn't most people need to test multiple type of data sets to see if the model can accept them? (ps: I am a noobie in unit-testing). If not, please explain why not, and alternative? Will be really appreciated!

Comment: Looping violates the principle of One Assertion Per Test (OAPT.) We use OAPT to maintain clarity in tests, both in writing them and in reading them. There are plenty of links to be found arguing one way or the other. I firmly believe in OAPT.

Comment: @MBielski Cool! may I know under OAPT, what is the best way to use jasmine to test multiple sets of value for specific testing variable input? Will really appreciated! This is something I have no idea of!

Comment: You need to look at why you are testing each value. If testing the multiplication function is your goal, there is no need to test each value in the array. Passing that function through one test would suffice. That being said, you should also test how the function reacts to non-numeric input. Expect it to fail and see what you get. FWIW, @Chen answered your question correctly and you should accept the answer.

Comment: @MBielski I know that it seems pretty clear with such as simple case as it is multiplication function. But in the real world testing with datasets is a must since there can be lots of combinations, especially if you're doing integration tests. It's fine to keep in mind OAPT when possible, but sometimes is not. At least, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

i think the real problem is "input.size" at line "for(var x = 0; x < input.size; x++) {" . there is no such thing called "input.size". try input.length and your test will run as expected