# Wait time out error in selenium-webdriver and phantomJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, mocha.js

I am writing my automated test scripts using selenium-webdriver, phantomJS and mocha.

My script file is javascript file by nature.

I want to wait till an element() becomes completely visible. After it becomes visible, the element will be clicked.

Let me explain in details:

There are some menus and submenus. The menu is collapsible in nature. When I click on a menu, then its corresponding submenus are displayed.

My following script first iterates(And clicks) through the menu and then iterates and (should be) clicking the submenu.

```
for(var iMajor = 2; iMajor <= majorLinkLast ; iMajor++)
{   
    (function(iMajor){
        majorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/a";
        if(iMajor != 2)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(majorMenuXPath)).click().then((function(iMajor){
                for(var iMinor = 1; iMinor <= minorSize[iMajor] ; iMinor++)
                {
                    (function(iMajor, iMinor){
                        minorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/ul/li["+iMinor+"]/a";
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath)).then(function(eleMinor){
                            driver.wait(function(){
                                    return eleMinor.isDisplayed();
                                }, 20000).then(function(){
                                    eleMinor.isDisplayed().then(function(stat){
                                    console.log(stat);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    })(iMajor,iMinor)
                }
            })(iMajor));
        } 

    })(iMajor)
}
```

But I am getting message like this:

```
Track Revenue
Track Revenue
Track Revenue
Track Revenue
Track Revenue
Track Revenue
Campaigns
    1) View page by clicking menu


  2 passing (1m)
  1 failing

  1) TrackRevenue Click Menu Test View page by clicking menu:
     Error: timeout of 50000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being cal
led in this test.
```

Why am I getting such output?

The title should have been different.

Please help.

Comment: How is this question duplicate of the one you mentioned? It specifically involves selenium issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait for element to be displayed before clicking on it. When you say that you are getting the displayed status as `true`, selenium waits for few seconds (default timeout interval) before throwing error and meanwhile your element gets displayed, so its printing true in console. In order to click on the required element, first wait for it to get displayed. Here's how to do it -

```
var ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath));
driver.wait(function() {
    return ele.isDisplayed();
}, 20000)
.then(function(){
    ele.click();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `var ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath));
       driver.wait(function() {
        return ele.isDisplayed();
       }, 20000)
       .then(function(){
        ele.click();
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
        {
         console.log(title);
        });
       });` Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Your click is working now? or its failing along with getting title?

Comment: Its failing along. Lets me update my question, based on your answer

Comment: @SunainaSingh your script is printing the same value everytime because for loop is being executed without waiting for any element to be found and console logged. To resolve this issue here's a link. Your loops should also be similar to it - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/27910350/4180674](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27910350/4180674) or [http://stackoverflow.com/a/23635357/4180674](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23635357/4180674)

Comment: Could you help me is rearranging my code? I would be grateful.

Comment: Here's a small [gist](https://gist.github.com/girishsortur/223ebe6cd92b8c2e3b70) to help you

Comment: Thanks, but it states funcs is not defined

Comment: updated gist to remove the funcs variable.

Comment: Now its stating unexpected Token

Comment: Can you create a gist of your complete file or update the existing gist that i shared above? and comment there so that we can resolve it.

Comment: How can I create a gist?

Comment: Hello, How can I update the gist?

Comment: Go to github and login with your id. Later click on gists link on top and then create one with your code.

Comment: I don't have any github id of my own. Can I use someone else's?

Comment: Here's the [https://gist.github.com/sunainasingh/266028ea5a587e098b51]

Comment: Hello, are you there?

Comment: I saw your code and it looks ok. Remove the semi-colon's at the end of functions(). Also can you paste your complete error logs as well in a gist or update it here.