# protractor looping through paramaters for baseUrl

Tags: loops, typescript, protractor, angular5

I want to alter the baseUrl to contain paramaters from a json, to open a different url to run a test for each market i have. How do i go about that? This is what i have so far. 
protractor - 5.1.2
typescript: 2.4.2

locales.json

```
{
  "markets": ["us", "uk", "ca"]
}
```

config.js

```
  params: { 
       data:require('./e2e/testdata/locales.json') ,
       baseUrl: 'https://mywebsite' + markets[i] + '.com' //should get all items from json
  },
```

spec.ts
      beforeEach(() => {

```
    page = new PageObject();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);  
    browser.get(baseUrl); // i want the test to run more than once, for all items in json file

  });
```

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634558/looping-on-a-protractor-test-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to loop through my json file and alter the baseUrl each time. But the browser doesnt open each baseUrl in a different instance, it stays in the same window. My tests passes, but i dont see if it ran the 3 times i wanted it to. I only see it run on the last item that was in the loop.

```
beforeEach(() => {

    page = new PageObject();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    for (var i = 0; i < market.length; i++) {
      var marketParam = market[i];
      let baseUrl: 'https://mywebsite' + marketParam + '.com'
      browser.get(baseUrl);
    }
  });
```

Comment: i figured it out. I didnt have the test in the loop ;)